# How to close a emacsclient gui frame without killing the server

Tags: emacs, emacsclient

How do you **close an emacsclient frame without killing the server/daemon**?

Doing `C-x C-c` or `C-x 5 0` in the gui will exit both frame and server (and other clients), while this just quit the current frame when done from terminal.

(Ps: My emacs version is 24.2,gtk. I've tried without init-file to see if it was coming from my config, but results were the same)

Comment: For a long time I had issues with the gtk builds of emacs and switched to another toolkit. The folks in the #emacs channel on freenode noted that this is a long standing bug somewhere in gtk that causes the server to crash. Try a build using the lucid toolkit.

Answer (score 12):

From the minibuffer, when `emacsclient` starts:

> When done with a buffer, type C-x #

Comment: `C-x #` also kill the server when realised from the gui

Comment: It certainly doesn't do that for me.

Comment: I know it's not supposed to. :/
What version are you using?

Comment: Emacs 23.4.1 with Gtk (standard Debian version).

Comment: It works just as well with both `emacsclient -c` and `emacsclient -t`, by the way.

Comment: it work perfectly with `emacsclient -t`, but not `emacsclient -c`. (was implying this with terminal/gui)
Gonna try with the last version from ppa:cassou/emacs.

Comment: Are you sure your server doesn't just segfault or something, rather than quits intentionally?

Comment: There is nothing on the stderr from the terminal I launched it (where are displayed init messages). Otherwise don't know how to check this

Comment: A segfaulting program normally wouldn't print anything on stderr. However, most shells should normally inform you if a foreground process terminates on a signal (other than `SIGINT`, at least).

Comment: after checking it's not a segfault, exitcode is 0. 
Also, nothing new with emacs24.3.1....either with or without config.

Comment: Do you start your server by starting a regular Emacs process and then calling `server-start` in it, or with `emacs --daemon`?

Comment: By calling `server-start` in a regular process. However, it works just as well if I start a server with `emacs --daemon`. EDIT: In fact, even `C-x C-c` works for exiting just the client without terminating the daemon.

Comment: after some testing, it happens that for some unknow reason, this will "work" if an other client is "visible" when closing the gui client.   (in a tmux terminal). don't ask me why...

Comment: It sounds like you have some very specific bug or something and should ask on the Emacs mailing list or so instead. :)

Answer (score 6):

I think the key point here is you need to start the server in daemon mode. If the server runs in an existing emacs process - for instance if you have `(server-start)` in your init file - the server dies with the emacs process.

There are a couple of ways of starting the server in daemon mode:

- call `emacs` with the `--daemon` command line option
- call `emacsclient` with the `--alternate-editor=""` command line option, which will in effect run `emacs --daemon` for you then attempt to connect to it

Once you have the server in daemon mode, you should be able to close any frames and the daemon will continue to sit and wait for further connections.

Answer (score 4):

Starting the `emacsclient` with `-n`/`--no-wait` flag will:

> Don't wait for the server to return

You won't need to close the client in that case.

And if you have to a close `emacsclient` just kill the buffer the server will remain intact.

Answer (score 2):

Because you ran `(server-start)` from an existing frame, that frame is not an emacsclient frame, and closing the last such frame evidently gets the same treatment as `C-x C-c`: it will exit Emacs.

If you used `emacs --daemon`, possibly using the `ALTERNATE_EDITOR=''` trick, you would not have this problem; you could just use `emacsclient -n -c` to open a GUI frame, and after closing it the daemon would just sit around waiting for you to open a new frame, whether graphical or terminal-based.

Comment: I even start it via systemd, as described at WikEmacs: http://wikemacs.org/wiki/Emacs_server#Adding_To_OS_Startup

Answer (score 1):

I am using both Debian with i3, and OSX. I usually exit emacsclient GUI frame by the window manager's close window shortcut. For example, in OSX, I use "Command + w" to close the client GUI frame without killing the server, and in i3, I use "Super + Shift + q" (the default close window by i3) to exit the client frame.

Answer (score 0):

In modern version GNU Emacs(27+), it says

> When done with this frame, type C-x 5 0